# Looping through properties within a class and assigning values (VB.Net)

Tags: vb.net

My current coding setup is as follows:

```
Public Class ListValue
   Public Property type As String
   Public Property values As List(Of Long)
End Class

Public Class DataStructures
   Public Property ListA as listValue
   Public Property ListB as listValue
   Public Property ListC as listValue
   Public Property ListD as listValue

   Public Property dataType as string
   Public Property otherData as long

End Class

Public Class Form1
   ...
   ...

   Private Sub addNumberToLists(number as Integer)

     '[Loop through all the lists and add the number to them]

   End Sub

End Class
```

---

Based on the above, I want the 'addNumberToLists' sub to loop through all of the properties in the 'DataStructures' class and if it's a listValue type, and the number to the values list, within that type.

E.g:

```
For each list as listValue in DataStructures
    list.values.add(Number)
    list.type = "Number"
Next
```

After looking around, I found this method and it does get me each property, but not too sure how I access the propertyInfo value as if it was a listValue type:

```
Private Sub addNumberToLists(number as Integer)
  Dim _type as Type = DataStructures.GetType()
  Dim properties() As Reflection.PropertyInfo = _type.GetProperties()

  For Each property as Reflection.PropertyInfo in properties
    if property.GetType() = listValue

      [ADD EXTRA CODE HERE]

    end if
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You could put your list in a Dictionary(Of String, ListValue) and access them with a key

Comment: It is always a Long in this code.  Pretty unlikely that is what you want, create a "property bag" with the System.Dynamics.ExpandoObject class.